# Merge tags "pisa" and "pisa-pdf"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Both tags [pisa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pisa) and [pisa-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pisa-pdf) refer to the same tool to generate Pdf from HTML.
As [pisa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pisa)  wiki says: "Pisa is a Python HTML/XHTML/CSS to PDF converter"

No wiki instead for tag [pisa-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pisa-pdf)  (which obviously refers to the same package), so I suggest to merge the two tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I manually retagged all 9 questions in [pisa-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pisa-pdf) to [pisa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pisa).

Comment: How to get rid of old tag?

Comment: @Don: Just wait for 24 hours for the system to clean up unused tag.